# App bundles, but can't load assets from a node module at runtime

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm building an application that is loading assets from a node_module.  Everything bundles fine, but on runtime when I navigate to my page, it's failing to find the webfonts used by the scss file I'm importing from a node module.

I see this error in the browser's javascript console:

`bundle.js:129 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../fonts/webfonts/SalesforceSans-Light.woff2"`

The node module I'm importing my scss from is structured like so:

`@salesforce-ux/design-system/
├── assets
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── webfonts
│   │       └── [...all the fonts...]
│   ├── icons
│   ├── images
│   └── styles
├── scss
│   ├── index.scss
└── swatches`

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/myapp.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'eslint', exclude: /node_modules/}
        ],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel', query: { presets: ['es2015'] } },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap','resolve-url','sass?sourceMap'], //the resolve-url loader is important
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My app.js:

```
'use strict';


var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

My style sheet:

```
@import "~@salesforce-ux/design-system/scss/index.scss";

body {
  background: #eee;

  h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm new to node and webpack, so if there's any additional code you need to see or insight, let me know.

Comment: The problem here is the relative pathing in the salesforce stylesheet. You can see the `../fonts/webfonts...` error which is caused by webpack because at the time of compilation the sass entry point becomes the root of your style references. However, `../fonts` likely does not exist, because it is in node_modules. Personally, I include their `css` (if available) and have a separate loader in my webpack for just css.